# How's it fair for a moderator to delete my account and dissociate my questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-accounts, moderator-messages

### Edit

I found the email that proves a moderator deleted my account. And nobody appears to believe me before?

Even if you suspend me, why dissociate my questions and answers? How can I manage or track them, or accept answers?

[image]

### Original

1. Moderator messaged me at Personal Finance S.E. How am I supposed to see if when they deleted my account? When I click on "moderator message", I get 404 not found page.
2. Why is this being down-voted?

Many people don't believe me that a moderator deleted my old account.

3. Yesterday when I logged on, I saw "Join this community", but I never deleted my Money account. I then clicked "Join this community" to see what happened.
4. Screen shot beneath undeniably proves this wasn't my old account when I asked at least 5 questions. It's unquestionably false that "you have not asked any questions."
5. Please reinstate my old account? I want to keep track of my posts.

I can't post on Money Meta. Please don't betray private details.

> [image]

and:

> [image]

Comment: [Your account](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/91921/mark-da-silva) on Finance.SE is suspended, not deleted (unless this was one that you created after the deletion).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose it WAS deleted. how else do you explain 3 and 4?

Comment: 3. Did you try logging in, instead of registering a new one?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose See my edit. Was it that hard for you to consider the possibility of deletion before?

Comment: @Luuklag See my edit. Was it that hard for you to consider the possibility of deletion before?

Comment: I *did* consider deletion, hence the second half of my comment. In the end, it doesn't matter what I think. Only a moderator of Money.se or a CM can see what happened to your account

Comment: You should use the contact form to ask for any further clarifications, as we are not able to give you those. Expect answers to take a few weeks.

Answer (score 12):

It was probably sent to the email associated with your account if you claim your account was deleted before you could read the message, so you might want to check your email.

But what you describe is unusual - a moderator wouldn't send you a moderator mail and promptly delete your account afterwards.

Comment: I didn't get an email. But you don't explain 3 and 4?

Comment: @MarkdaSilva I don't know, maybe you were logged out? Did you try logging back in?

Comment: See my edit. I don't know why you didn't consider the possibility of deletion before.

Comment: @MarkdaSilva Your questions and answers were not deleted, rather disassociated from your account and placed under a generic name (user`xxxxxx`).

Comment: How's that fair? And why the heck for this dissociation? I'm already suspended. What does dissociation do?

Comment: @MarkdaSilva Since you claim your account was *deleted*, that means all of the content you posted is reverted to an anonymous username. But I have no idea if your account was deleted or suspended.

Comment: Didn't you read my edit? "offending accounts will be removed". This means deleted.

Comment: @MarkdaSilva Exactly. What else do you need?

Comment: you didn't appear to believe me.

Comment: and can you change or delete your answer? it's false that "a moderator wouldn't send you a moderator mail and promptly delete your account afterwards." a moderator did DELETE.

Answer (score 7):

You ask:

> how does it assist humanity not to see my questions and answers
>   written by other people?

There is nothing in the moderator’s message that says the questions from a removed account will cause the questions and answers written by other people to be removed.

My understanding is that the posts by the removed account will no longer be associated with you, and that questions and answers by other people that form part of those Q&As will still be present, and eligible for votes by other than the removed account.

Comment: "the posts by the removed account will no longer be associated with you" how's this fair at all?